# How to Create stream without fileupload on server side in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

This is my code write with vb.net

```
Dim path As String = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName
Dim fileStream As Stream = File.OpenRead(path)
```

This code is select file in serverside but i want to select file in clientside. What should I do. Thank you very much.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It is not clear what exactly do you want to achive?

Comment: Post your code what you tried.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds like you want to access the client filesystem from the server. That is not possible.

Comment: you can read allbytes from file.